# Add Blueprint to a Rails 3 project using compass gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blueprint-css, compass-sass

I have a new Rails 3 project. I have installed Compass. I would like to generate the stylesheets in app/stylesheets using the Blueprint framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compass init rails /path/to/myrailsproject --using blueprint/semantic`

Accept the defaults when prompted; your Sass files will be put in `app/stylesheets` and the compiled css will be put in `public/stylesheets/compiled`.